# Where can I find an alternative to dxcontent monster db

Tags: pathfinder-1e, tools, online-resources

So I often find it a serious pain to find monsters and spells with very specific properties via the srd and low and behold the tool I usually use (the advanced monster search on dxcontent.com) is down. That tool is invaluable as I often search for fairly specific things. For example the other day I needed to find a list of incorporeal undead creatures below 4 cr for research on how low ranking incorporeal monsters interact with the environment. After that, I went through outsiders fey and a couple of other types of monsters. Just skimming the srd would have taken way to long.

Where can I find a tool to replace [DX Content's Monster DB](http://dxcontent.com/MDB_FilterTools_Wrapper.html)?

Comment: @Fering looks perfect it's also easier on the eyes than the dxcontent one thanks

Comment: @Fering please don't answer in comments.

Comment: @NautArch The question was closed so where else was an answer supposed to go?